# Are Windows Security hide some methods from .NET classes?

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

I'm working under windows Server 2008 :S
with restricted user not administrator.
using Visual Studio 2010

I try to run write this code

```
ApplicationClass app = new ApplicationClass();
Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Open("");
Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1];
Picture pict = sheet.Pictures(pictureName) as Picture;
```

**Pictures()** method not exist in **sheet** object !

**But**
When I try this code under windows 7 with Administrator user
The Picture() method is exist and every thing is OK

I wonder, if there is some thing with interop and windows security ?

Comment: Well, given the fact that you're performing the same test on different operating system, I would suspect that the reason might be OS-dependant SDK rather than your security settings (i.e. your access-token) dependant.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the same Excel version on both machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you visit the MSDN page for this, I can see two issues:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.pictures.aspx

1. This API supports the Visual Studio infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.
2. Full trust for the immediate caller. This member cannot be used by partially trusted code. For more information, see Using Libraries from Partially Trusted Code.

It seems the reason is indeed a restricted user. Is there a reason you are using this API since documentation suggests that it should not be used directly. Perhaps you are missing a wrapper.